# Please suggest what is wrong with this string reversal function?

Tags: c++, string

This code is compiling clean. But when I run this, it gives exception "Access violation writing location" at line 9.

```
void reverse(char *word)
{
int len = strlen(word);
len = len-1;
char * temp= word;
int i =0;
while (len >=0)
{
word[i] = temp[len];  //line9
++i;--len;
}
word[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `std::reverse`?

Comment: Am I reading that right? It looks as if you're reversing _twice_ by reversing every character in the string... A <-> B then B <-> A...

Comment: Also, `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned, while `int` is signed. You should use the `size_t` type for string/array lengths and sizes. `int` isn't "good enough."

Comment: @fbrereto: Look more carefully, it's worse than this.

Comment: I think it will be better to use `word` length as function parameter. 
Your while in last iteration is looking like `word[i] = temp[-1];` You need to rethink Your code.

Comment: Clearly temp is meant to be a copy of the input _string_, rather than a copy of the pointer.  but that's not the only problem here.

Comment: @AKS: You've edited the question and change the source code, which is fine, but is the question still correct? Do you still get the access violation on writing?

Comment: yes, i edited the code in the while loop. temp[len-1] was a typo. but even now i can see the same crash happening.

Comment: @AKS: Then you need to show the calling code as well. Although there are other problems with your function's code, there's most likely an issue with the parameter that is being passed in.

Comment: @AKS: Seriously. `std::reverse(word, word + strlen(word));`. Done. If you still get problems with the standard reverse function, then the problem is in your calling code, not the reverse function.

Answer (score 7):

Have you stepped through this code in a debugger?

If not, what happens when `i` (increasing from 0) passes `len` (decreasing towards 0)?

Note that your two pointers `word` and `temp` have the same value - they are pointing to the same string.

Comment: Nail head? Meet hammer. Not once, not twice, but three times. Big +1

Comment: Yes. I am running it in debugger. When I replace the target in the while loop(char *word) with another char array(lets say char dest[20]), the code is working fine. I am wondering why its not working when I am using the same char *word.

Comment: Step through the debugger with a test string that is "important          ". That's the word _important_ followed by ten spaces. After nine iterations, what has happened?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful: not all strings in a C++ program are writable. Even if your code is good it can still crash when someone calls it with a string literal.

Comment: Um...if it's been passed into the function he quoted, it's not his problem. There's no `const` in the argument declaration.

Comment: @T.J: it's his problem if he also wrote the calling code. Which is overwhelmingly likely. But this code can crash even without being passed a string literal, so who knows?

Comment: @Steve: Disagree that it's likely at all. Completely agree there are a bunch of other (and much more significant) issues with the code.

Comment: @T.J: really? So who did write the calling code? My thought process is that the questioner clearly wrote this `reverse` function himself, so he probably wrote the harness to call it himself, too. Surely no teacher/tutorial would be so sneaky as to set an assignment where even if you implement the function correctly, it still crashes because the teacher-provided calling code is wrong. Or are C++ instructors more sadistic than I thought?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: this code can crash on a _read_ violation, but not a _write_ violation unless the input is unwritable.

Comment: @John: fair point. I agree that (most likely) the cause of the write violation is that a string literal is being passed in. I disagree with T.J. that this isn't the questioner's problem, but I intended to concede to T.J that since the stated question is "what's wrong *with this function*", and there clearly are things wrong with this function, things that are wrong with the calling code are beyond our current certain knowledge...

Answer (score 3):

When `len` gets to 0, you access the location before the start of the string (`temp[0-1]`).

Comment: That's *one* problem. There are several others.

Comment: Yeah, at many levels. The more I look at this, the more I think it is a "debug my homework" question.

Comment: That can't cause a _write_ crash, that would be a _read_ crash.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void reverse(char *word)
{
  size_t len = strlen(word);
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
    {
      char temp = word[i];
      word[i] = word[len - i - 1];
      word[len - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function looks like it would not crash, but it won't work correctly and it will read from word[-1], which is not likely to cause a crash, but it is a problem.  Your crashing problem is probably that you passed in a string literal that the compiler had put into a read-only data segment.

Something like this would crash on many operating systems.

```
char * word = "test";
reverse(word); // this will crash if "test" isn't in writable memory
```

There are also several problems with your algorithm. You have `len = len-1`  and later `temp[len-1]` which means that the last character will never be read, and when len==0, you will be reading from the first character *before* the word. Also, temp and word are both pointers, so they both point to the same memory,  I think you meant to make a *copy* of word rather than just a copy of the pointer to word.  You can make a copy of `word` with [strdup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html).  If you do that, and fix your off-by-one problem with len, then your function should work,

But that still won't fix the write crash, which is caused by code that you have not shown us.

Oh, and if you do use `strdup` be sure to call `free` to free `temp` before you leave the function.

Comment: Making a copy with strdup in a function that takes a non-const parameter and returns `void` doesn't sound right to me. I think it's *supposed* to be an in-place reverse, it's just not quite right yet.

Comment: temp[len -1] is a typo. Sorry about that

Comment: @Steve Jessop: There's no need for temp at all with an inplace reverse, but there's so many problems here, its impossible to know.

Comment: Agreed. When I read it, I thought "whoever wrote this code has seen string-mangling functions which increment pointers, started to copy that style, and then bottled it and gone for indexes instead". It didn't occur to me that the questioner thought he was taking a copy of the string, but now I see your point. At this level, though, I'd say that if you suggest calling `strdup`, suggest calling `free` too, because it's not going to occur to the student otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, when `len == 0` len-1 will be a negative number. And that's pretty illegal. Second, it's quite possible that your pointer is pointing at an unreserved area of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you called that function as followed:

```
reverse("this is a test");
```

then with at least one compiler will pass in a read only string due to backwards compatibility with C where you can
pass string literals as non-const char*.